# Change the size of one cell in excel 2016

Tags: excel

I want to change the width and height of one or some cells in **Excel 2016**

I know how to change the size of a total row or column but i need it for some cells not all of the row or column, In other words i don't want changing the size of this cell to affect the whole row and column

[image: Two cells]

Like the previous tiny image which i am trying to manipulate the cells so they look like

Comment: One way to get a large cell and avoid changing column width or row height is to use ***merged cells***.

Comment: And how to reduce ?

Comment: It's not possible for one cell without changing column and row dimensions.

Comment: I do not know......

Comment: @JvdV i appreciate your comment but are you sure ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure...

Comment: @JvdV In case you want to make it an answer so i refer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. A cell has to fit in it's matrix (height of it's row and width of it's column). You could however merge cells, although it's technically not the same as changing dimensions of one cell.

Note, I wouldn't recommend merged cells as they can bring a lot of trouble in future work on your spreadsheet e.g. selecting rows or columns.

Answer (score 1):

*After a fashion* both many to one:

[image: many to one]

and one to many:

[image]

are possible but neither is likely to be of much use, since the former is a text box and the latter an image and neither the cell nor these cells can be accessed in the normal way by Excel formulae. Even merging (generally a very bad idea) would be of limited use since only the top left corner (even if appearing to fill the entire cell) of a merged range is accessible by Excel formulae.

So really what is left for these to be of use is for presentation purposes, perhaps organisation charts or maybe to represent the workings of a 3D formula or such like.